# Filter the array based on another array Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

I have two arrays

```
 {
"products": [
    {
        "name": "Jivi",
        "Hint": "45-60 IE/kg alle 5 Tage\n60 IE 1x/Woche\n30-40 IE 2 x/Woche",
        "frequency": ["1", "2", "8"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Adynovi",
        "Hint": "40-50 IE/kg 2x/Woche im Abstand von 3-4 Tagen",
        "frequency": ["2", "6", "7"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Esperoct",
        "Hint": "\"50 IE/kg \nalle 4 Tage\"\n",
        "frequency": ["7"]
    }
],
"haufigkeit" : [
    {
        "name": "1x / Woche",
        "id": 1,
        "value": 52.1428571429
    },
    {
        "name": "2x / Woche",
        "value": 104.2857142857143,
        "id": 2
    }
]
}
```

I have a select dropdown using Vuejs where the `products.name` are rendering.

```
 <select v-model="selectFrequency">
        <option v-for="(level1,index) in dataJson.products"
                v-bind:value="level1.frequency">{{level1.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

For example, When I select `Jivi`, I would like to compare the numbers in `frequency` of `products` with `id` in `haufigkeit` and when they matches, then display the `name` of `haufigkeit`

Here is what I am trying

```
computed:{
selectFrequency:function(){
    let results= this.haufigkeit.filter(array=>array.every(item => this.products.filter(group=>group.frequency.includes(item))));
}
}
```

I have been trying for two days and it gives me an error `cannot read property 'every' of undefined`. Can anyone suggest me where I have done mistake?

Comment: `haufigkeit.filter(array=>array.every(item ...`
Inside the haufigkeit.filter function, `array` is an individual item from the array so it's an object with the keys name, value and id.
By doing `array.every` you expect array to be an array but in fact it's not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Ok now I understand, something like this should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/q9grc04s/

If you select a product you will see it displays any haufigkeit that have an ID included in the selected frequency.

```
<template>
<div>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selectedFrequency">
      <option
        v-for="(level1, i) in products"
        :key="i"
        :value="level1.frequency"
      >
        {{level1.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Haufigkeit Matches:</h1>
    <ul v-if="haufigkeitMatches">
      <li v-for="match in haufigkeitMatches">{{ match.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    selectedFrequency: [],
    products: [
        {
            name: "Jivi",
            Hint: "45-60 IE/kg alle 5 Tage\n60 IE 1x/Woche\n30-40 IE 2 x/Woche",
            frequency: [1, 2, 8]
        },
        {
            name: "Adynovi",
            Hint: "40-50 IE/kg 2x/Woche im Abstand von 3-4 Tagen",
            frequency: [2, 6, 7]
        },
        {
            name: "Esperoct",
            Hint: "\"50 IE/kg \nalle 4 Tage\"\n",
            frequency: [7]
        }
    ],
    haufigkeit : [
        {
            name: "1x / Woche",
            id: 1,
            value: 52.1428571429
        },
        {
            name: "2x / Woche",
            value: 104.2857142857143,
            id: 2
        }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    haufigkeitMatches(){
        return this.haufigkeit.filter(x => this.selectedFrequency.includes(x.id))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note: sorry for all the edits, i'm trying to get to grips with the stackoverflow editor, the JS fiddle link is a working solution though.

Comment: Hi, I have corrected my post., I am using ````this.```` and still I get the same error.

Comment: Thats a great working solution. Thanks a lot... A small correction I need in your solution. Can I also use ```v-bind:value="level1"``` instead of ```v-bind:value="level1.frequency"``` in select the attritbute by changing the constant results to ```const results = this.haufigkeit.filter(x => this.selectedFrequency.frequency.includes(x.id))``` like this?

I want to do this because, at some point, I have to render ```Hint``` property also based on selected ````Jivi```.

Comment: Yes! That has helped me a lot. I have tried this method already, But I have declared ```selectedProduct: [ ]``` instead of ```null``` which was throwing me error . Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Javascript some](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript.php) function. in the below example I'm returning the id's of the haufigkeit array which are equal to the frequencies of the products

```js
var data = {
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Jivi",
            "Hint": "45-60 IE/kg alle 5 Tage\n60 IE 1x/Woche\n30-40 IE 2 x/Woche",
            "frequency": ["1", "2", "8"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Adynovi",
            "Hint": "40-50 IE/kg 2x/Woche im Abstand von 3-4 Tagen",
            "frequency": ["2", "6", "7"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Esperoct",
            "Hint": "\"50 IE/kg \nalle 4 Tage\"\n",
            "frequency": ["7"]
        }
    ],
    "haufigkeit" : [
        {
            "name": "1x / Woche",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 52.1428571429
        },
        {
            "name": "2x / Woche",
            "value": 104.2857142857143,
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
};

var result = [];
function selectFrequency(){

    data.products.forEach(elem => {
      
        elem.frequency.forEach(fre =>{
            var arr = data.haufigkeit;
            if(arr.some(arr => arr.id == fre))
                result.push(fre);
        })
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(selectFrequency());
```